# Trouble with Twig `embed` tag

Tags: embed

I'm trying to embed the sidebar and define which blocks to display.

```
{% embed "_partials/sidebar" %}
    {% block instagram %}{% endblock %}
    {% block subscribe %}{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

sidebar.html is

```
{% block subscribe %}
    block content
{% endblock %}
```

But it doesn't show anything and no errors as well (dev mode enabled).

The idea is make a dynamic sidebar and define which widgets I'd like to see in each template.

This is what I use right now.

```
        {% set widgets = {
            'about'     : true,
            'instagram' : true,
            'menu'      : false,
            'recipes'   : true,
            'subscribe' : true
        } %}

        {% include "_partials/sidebar" with {
            widgets: widgets
        } %}
```

sidebar.html

```
       {% if widgets.menu == 'true' %}
           content
       {% endif %}
```

is there any other more flexible approaches for this?

Comment: I've personally never found a good reason to use `embed`. It's a strange tag... I use `extends` and `include` 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that, as per the use cases [in the documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/tags/embed.html), `embed` is a good fit for your requirements.

If you're not sure, `extends` and `include` are probably a better choice, as they're much easier to understand and work with.

Moving on, in your example you appear to have confused the roles of the template being embedded, and the template doing the embedding.

Here's how it should look:

```
{# Page (doing the embedding) #}
{% embed "_partials/sidebar" %}
    {% block subscribe %}
        The custom subscribe block content.
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}

{# Embed (being embedded) #}
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar__subscribe">
        {% block subscribe %}
            The (optional) default subscribe block content.
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```